# Set value of ngMaterial autocomplete without request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I'm using AngularJS with Angular Material. I have several cascading autocompletes. But when I select a value in one of them I want to set the value of another autocomplete. All data comes from server asynchronously.

Here's some code. Markup:

```
 <md-autocomplete md-input-name="cityInput"
     md-min-length="3"
     md-search-text="searchCity"
     md-items="item in getCities(searchCity)"
     md-item-text="item.Name"
     md-selected-item-change="selectedCity(item)"
     placeholder="Search..."
     required>
       <md-item-template>
         <span>{{item.Name}}</span>
       </md-item-template>
       <md-not-found>
         Nothing found
       </md-not-found>
  </md-autocomplete>

<md-autocomplete md-input-name="tradeCenterInput"
    md-min-length="3"
    md-search-text="searchTradeCenter"
    md-items="item in getTradeCenters(searchTradeCenter)"
    md-item-text="item.Name"
    md-selected-item-change="selectedTradeCenter(item)"
    placeholder="Search..."
    md-no-cache="true"
    required>
      <md-item-template>
        <span>{{item.Name}}</span>
      </md-item-template>
      <md-not-found>
        Nothing found
      </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

And here's some JS for that:

```
$scope.searchUrlTradeCenter = globalSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "/dir/searchTradeCenter/";
        $scope.getTradeCenters = function (searchText) {
            var url = $scope.searchUrlTradeCenter + searchText + "/" + ($scope.merchantPostalAddress.CityId != null ? $scope.merchantPostalAddress.CityId : 'NULL');
            return $http.get(url, {
                withCredentials: true
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }

$scope.searchUrlCity = globalSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "/dir/searchCity/";
        $scope.getCities = function (searchText) {
            var url = $scope.searchUrlCity + ($scope.postalAddressComplete[0] != null ? $scope.postalAddressComplete[0] : 'NULL') + "/" + ($scope.postalAddressComplete[1] != null ? $scope.postalAddressComplete[1] : 'NULL') + "/" + searchText;
            return $http.get(url, {
                withCredentials: true
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }

$scope.selectedTradeCenter = function (tradeCenter) {
            if (tradeCenter) {
                $scope.merchant.TradeCenterId = tradeCenter.DirectoryId;
                if (tradeCenter.Address.City != null) {
                    $scope.selectedCity({ Name: tradeCenter.Address.City.Name, DirectoryId: tradeCenter.Address.City.CityId.toString() });
                }
            }
            else {
                $scope.merchant.TradeCenterId = null;
            }
        };

$scope.selectedCity = function (city) {
            if (city) {
                $scope.merchantPostalAddress.CityId = city.DirectoryId;
                $scope.postalAddressComplete[2] = city.Name;
            }
            else {
                $scope.postalAddressComplete.splice(2, 1, undefined);
                $scope.merchantPostalAddress.CityId = null;
            }

            $scope.CompleteAddresses = $.grep($scope.postalAddressComplete, Boolean).join(", ");
        };
```

So when I select a trade center, I want to specify a city, if it has it. List of cities at that moment hasn't loaded yet. Any workarounds for that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Needed to add `md-selected-item` attribute to `md-autocomplete` tag and then in JS it is possible to set the value for that variable. Final markup and JS are below.
HTML:

```
<md-autocomplete md-input-name="cityInput"
     md-min-length="3"
     md-search-text="searchCity"
     md-items="item in getCities(searchCity)"
     md-item-text="item.Name"
     md-selected-item="selectedCityItem"
     md-selected-item-change="selectedCity(item)"
     placeholder="Search..."
     required>
       <md-item-template>
         <span>{{item.Name}}</span>
       </md-item-template>
       <md-not-found>
         Nothing found
       </md-not-found>
  </md-autocomplete>
```

JavaScript:

```
...
$scope.selectedCityItem = { Name: data.City.Name, Id: data.City.CityId };
...
```